# Java conversion of an image by constraining proportions and downscale only using iText

Tags: java, image, itext, scale, pixel

I have a simple Java application that takes in an image of varying size and outputs it into a PDF. It is using the class `com.lowagie.text.Image` (a class used with iText <= 2.1.7) and when importing the image, the pixel dimensions and dpi are known.

I want to display the image if it does not violate the constraints of an 8.5"x11" piece of paper. If it is too wide, I need it to determine the percent decrease in width to calculate what the change in height would be in calculating the final width and height of the image on the PDF. The opposite would be true if constraining by height, if the image is too tall. Finally, if it is too wide AND too tall, I need to determine which is the greater percent decrease and decrease both height and width by that value.

I do NOT want to upscale images falling within the 8.5x11 constraints (e.g. 8.5x11 -> 11x14) but only downscale images that are too large.

Here are my known values:

```
Original Width
Original Height
DPI
```

Here is just many of the attempts I've tried, but none of them work. I'd appreciate any help!

`PlainW` is the original width of the image, while `PlainH` is the original height.

```
if (PlainW >= 612) { //x is over or equal
    xDiff = PlainW - 612;
    xScale = PlainW / 612;
    if (PlainH < 792) { //y is under
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH == 792) { //y is equal
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) { //y is over
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    }
} else if (PlainW < 612) { //x is under
    xDiff = 612 - PlainW;
    xScale = PlainW / 162;
    if (PlainH < 792) { //y is under
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH == 792) { //y is equal
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) { //y is over
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a version of iText which is at least 7 years old. Please don't do that. Use a current version, either 5.5.10 or 7.0.1. Your code also uses a lot of conditionals, it hurts my head to read and to try to understand it. For example, why is `yScale = PlainH / 792;` always inside every conditional? Secondly, you have conditionals that execute exactly the same code, why not combine them? Finally, if you have 2 values A and B, and you need the difference, then you do *not* compare them. You subtract and take the absolute value.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Do you know of a location where I can find easy steps to upgrade to iTextPDF 5? I am looking for which classes have changed (and thus what to import into my java file) and if any of the methods have changed.

Comment: From iText 2 to iText 5? Most of the time you only need to change `com.lowagie` to `com.itextpdf`. Take a look at http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/ and there's documentation at http://developers.itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is really hard to understand! I will show you how you can make it simpler.

This is your code:

```
if (PlainW >= 612) { //x is over or equal
    xDiff = PlainW - 612;
    xScale = PlainW / 612;
    if (PlainH < 792) { //y is under
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH == 792) { //y is equal
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) { //y is over
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    }
} else if (PlainW < 612) { //x is under
    xDiff = 612 - PlainW;
    xScale = PlainW / 162;
    if (PlainH < 792) { //y is under
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH == 792) { //y is equal
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) { //y is over
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
        yScale = PlainH / 792;
    }
}
```

Inside every conditional, you have `yScale = PlainH / 792;`, just put that outside, like this (additionally I got rid of the useless comments):

```
if (PlainW >= 612) {
    xDiff = PlainW - 612;
    xScale = PlainW / 612;
    if (PlainH < 792) {
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
    } else if (PlainH == 792) {
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) {
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
    }
} else if (PlainW < 612) {
    xDiff = 612 - PlainW;
    xScale = PlainW / 162;
    if (PlainH < 792) {
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
    } else if (PlainH == 792) {
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) {
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
    }
}
yScale = PlainH / 792;
```

Then you have some conditionals which do exactly the same, `yDiff = 792 - PlainH;`, just combine them like this:

```
if (PlainW >= 612) {
    xDiff = PlainW - 612;
    xScale = PlainW / 612;
    if (PlainH <= 792) {
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) {
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
    }
} else if (PlainW < 612) {
    xDiff = 612 - PlainW;
    xScale = PlainW / 162;
    if (PlainH <= 792) {
        yDiff = 792 - PlainH;
    } else if (PlainH > 792) {
        yDiff = PlainH - 792;
    }
}
yScale = PlainH / 792;
```

But wait! Comparing two integers and then subtracting the smallest from the largest? Why not just take the absolute value of the difference?

```
if (PlainW >= 612) {
    xDiff = PlainW - 612;
    xScale = PlainW / 612;
    yDiff = Math.abs(PlainH - 792);
} else if (PlainW < 612) {
    xDiff = 612 - PlainW;
    xScale = PlainW / 162;
    yDiff = Math.abs(PlainH - 792);
}
yScale = PlainH / 792;
```

Again, I see identical code inside a conditional. Move it to the outside!

```
if (PlainW >= 612) {
    xDiff = PlainW - 612;
} else if (PlainW < 612) {
    xDiff = 612 - PlainW;
}
xScale = PlainW / 612;
yDiff = Math.abs(PlainH - 792);
yScale = PlainH / 792;
```

Again, comparing 2 integers and subtracting the smallest from the largest can be replaced with `Math.abs`.

```
xDiff = Math.abs(PlainW - 612);
xScale = PlainW / 612;
yDiff = Math.abs(PlainH - 792);
yScale = PlainH / 792;
```

Look! Your code was reduced from 27 lines to just 4 lines, it contains **ZERO** conditionals, and it is a lot easier to understand!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will also look into updating my version of iText!